# H1-B Visa transfer from company A to company B

Tags: usa

I am from India and this is the first time I got the H1B visa stamped through Company A, But not traveled to US yet via H1-B visa (still in India) but my visa time period is still valid for next 2 years.

I have a good name with the Current employer (Company - B) and they will sponsor the H1B.

what are the documents needed and upcoming steps to transfer the visa from Company A to Company B?

**NOTE** : I haven't travelled through the stamped H1-B visa yet.

Any information on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have a site called [expatriates.se] that is for living and working abroad. Please ask there.

Answer (score 1):

> what are the documents needed and upcoming steps to transfer the visa from Company A to Company B?

All the same. Your company's lawyers should tell you the specific documents, but it's essentially the same petition that they'd be filing as the company A filed. The only difference is that you may be able to reuse the existing cap allocation and won't need to participate in the lottery or wait for April/October timelines for filing/activation.

Once your new H1b is approved - you don't actually need to issue a new visa sticker, as long as the old one is not expired you can still use it even if it states the old company name on it. Just have the new I797A with you when you go through the CBP inspection.